# I click on Network ID to "Join a Domain or Workgroup" and set my computer to home computer, but after restart I am back at workgroup?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do I fix this? My computer is a single home computer and I don't want it to be a part of a workgroup of any kind?

It always returns to this, and I can't change to home PC:

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Are other computers on your home network and what are they set to.

Comment: no just a single pc

Comment: Is your home computer set to private before restart, re:Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center (click on Homegroup - it is bottom left under Also see)

Answer (score 6):

I think this is simply a misunderstanding regarding terminology.  A Windows 10 computer is part of a `Workgroup` by default, just like my home desktop:

[image: Workgroup]

There is nothing inherently wrong with that.  You many be confusing a `Workgroup` with a `Domain`, which corporations typically utilize.  The following explanation may help:

> Workgroups are small peer-to-peer local area networks, where each computer has its own set of rules and settings, managed by administrator of that device. As a result, workgroups are used mostly in home or small-business networks. In order to easily access another computer from the same network and share resources with it, both computers must be part of the same workgroup. Also, you need to have a user account defined on the computer you want to access. If you want to avoid that, users can share resources from their computers and set them so that they don't require authentication from others.

(Source:  [What is the Workgroup & How to Change it in Windows?](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-workgroup-windows-7))

Please take a look at your own screen shot: it specifically says `Join a Domain or Workgroup`. If you picked the top choice, it would guide you through the process to join a domain. The bottom choice says `This is a home computer; it's not part of a business network`. As a result, it defaults to a workgroup configuration for your home PC, as the heading at the top of that window implies:

[image: Join a Domain or Workgroup]

Comment: workgroup by default means business network....and I don't want to be a part of it

Comment: on your screenie, you can click on change settings, and then workrgroup....by default, its business network, and even if you change that to home computer, after restart its back to business network

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are you changing?

Comment: I am not talking about a domain dude. Just workgroup. Not homegroup, not domain, workgroup. I wish to leave it.

Comment: I understand that, and I have a firm grasp regarding all three of them.  But ultimately, your computer will belong to one of the above... you can't *leave* a workgroup unless it is for one of those other options, or another workgroup.  Unless there is another computer on your home network that belongs to a workgroup with the same name *and* had login credentials on your computer, you have nothing to worry about.  If you are still a bit concerned, you could change your workgroup name to something unique rather than the default.

Comment: what? Are you saying my single home pc must be a part of a larger group? I have to disagree. You build a homegroup if you have more then one home pc, you build a workgroup if you have more then one oc on the network, and you join a domain if you belong to one. My computer is neither of the mentioned and I fail to see the need of a single pc in a group of any kind. Its home pc, and it should stay solo.

Comment: No, it doesn't *need* to be part of a larger group. If you don't join a domain, it defaults to a workgroup. If there is nothing else on your home network that is configured for the same workgroup name, it really **is** a solo home PC. Please take a look at your own screen shot: it specifically says `Join a Domain or Workgroup`. If you picked the top choice, it would guide you to join a domain. The bottom choice says `This is a home computer; it's not part of a business network`. As a result, it defaults to a workgroup, as the heading at the top of that windows implies.

Comment: if I am a part of a workgroup whats stopping anyone from guessing my workgroup name and trying to get to resources? If there is 2 of something you may call it a group, if its just one thing, grouping is useless, not to mention risky...

Comment: Your caution is admirable, but it really is much more safe than you might think. First of all, someone would need to be on your own network, utilizing the same router, etc. Then, they would need to know your workgroup name (which can be easily changed to your preference). Next, they would need some type of login credentials on *your* computer to access the resources. Finally, you would need to enable `Turn on file and printer sharing`, which is off by default.  All of the above is **very** unlikely to happen!  Trust me, windows computers have defaulted to this setup for *many* years.

Comment: I agree with this answer and everything Run5k has written, for what it's worth. @user703825 you are perceiving a problem where *no problem exists*. A computer can't belong to *no* workgroup just by convention, but it's not a security issue. Workgroups are not a security feature. Firewalls and passwords are.

Comment: Allow me to agree with Run5k and allquixotic too. Your windows computer WILL identify itself on the network using one of these functions, and the Workgroup is the default "group" that a single personal Windows computer will identify as being part of. It has been this way for decades too. You may not like that, but it seems you're attributing some abilities and trust settings to workgroups that they don't actually have.